Multiple volume cross referencing and indexing
Context: I'm producing a new version of a book that I’ve generated before, but this time it’s been decided (not by me!) to switch to two volumes. The first volume will remain static for subsequent releases. (It’s a "descending" genealogy, and the first volume contains only the first few generations, consisting entirely of people who are already deceased.) My tentative plan is to use page numbering like I-13 and II-89, with the I and II indicating the volume.
The main problem I face is cross-references and indexing: people in Volume I have children that appear in Volume II, so on Mary Ellen Smith’s entry on page I-16, I need a pointer to her kids, Robin and Joseph, on pages II-82 and II-96. Similarly, on Robin’s and Joseph’s pages, I’ll need a back-reference to page I-16. The index for Volume II will also need to reference Volume I entries. The index for the first volume, however, should (for stability) refer only to Volume I.
I’ve looked at previous answers like this, this, and this, but they’re all about a decade old, and things do change.
Question: Which packages would you recommend for producing indexes and cross-references for a multi-volume book as of 2024/2025? Maybe it’s a solved problem and 10-year-old packages are still the standard, but maybe there’s a newer package that resolves earlier issues and makes this process smoother. (An example of this for me: longtable was life-changing when it finally arrived!)
By the way, I tried using the sample code from Igor’s final answer in this question and its predecessors, but I still ended up with (?) references in the output. So, maybe that 10-year-old code isn’t reliable anymore, or maybe I didn’t use it correctly—even though it was just a cut-and-paste job. I also tried running LaTeX on both 'main' files multiple times.

If I unerstand correctly, volume II may change in the future, while volume I is intended to remain static. But won't changes in volume II break references there from volume I? Or do you ensure that volume II will only be appended to, with no insertions or deletions in existing sections?

Great question. The 'index' for volume 1 refers only to volume 1, which is static (all the folks in it are dead). The people in the next generation after volume 1 will have to be the first few pages of volume 2, so that they will not change in subsequent editions. This presents some design challenges, but we're willing to live with those.

You could use either xr or zref-xr. You can also employ indextools for indexing. All these packages are included in TeX Live 2024 and are recently maintained. The choice depends on the complexity of the project and the need for extensibility.

Example solution for your use case, via zref-xr (newer and with more features) and indextools (a modern fork of your previously-encountered older imakeidx):
Cross-Referencing Between Volumes
Volume I (Static Volume)

Define Labels:
Ensure that all sections, figures, or other elements to be referenced are labeled using \label commands. For example:
\section{Mary Ellen Smith}
\label{sec:MaryEllen}



These labels will be referenced from Volume II.

Compile Volume I:
Compile Volume I to generate volume1.aux. This file will be used by Volume II for cross-referencing.

Volume II (Dynamic Volume):
\usepackage{zref-xr} % Enhanced cross-referencing
\zexternaldocument[I-]{volume1} % Reference Volume I with prefix 'I-'

Here, volume1 refers to the auxiliary file (volume1.aux) of Volume I.

Referencing Labels from Volume I:

Use the \zref command to reference elements in Volume I:
As discussed in Section \zref{I-sec:MaryEllen}, Mary Ellen Smith\ldots{}

This command will include the correct section or page number from Volume I, prefixed by I-.

Compilation Steps:


Compile Volume I first to ensure volume1.aux is available and up-to-date.
Place the volume1.aux file in the same directory as Volume II or adjust the path in \zexternaldocument.
Compile Volume II multiple times to resolve all cross-references (I'd suggest the use of latexmk).

Indexing Across Volumes
For indexing, use indextools, supporting multiple indexes and well-suited for this task.
\usepackage{indextools}
\makeindex[name=vol1, title=Index for Volume I]


\index[vol1]{Smith, Mary Ellen}

In Volume II:
\usepackage{indextools}
\makeindex[name=vol2, title=Index for Volume II]

\index[vol2]{Smith, Mary Ellen|see{Volume I, p.~\zref{I-sec:MaryEllen}}}

\printindex[vol2]

Note on Stability:
Volume I's index is static and refers only to Volume I entries. Volume II's index includes references to Volume I where necessary.
